# Tag synonym request: container vs containers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I do not have enough rep in either [containers](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers) or [container](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/container) to create a tag alias, but IMHO it would be needed, hence this request. If this gets agreement it would be worthy to get it done earlier rather than later, to prevent proliferation.

IMHO [containers](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers) (37 questions now) should be the tag and `container` (7 questions now and no tag description) should be the synonym.

I also wonder if there is something that can be done about [containers](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers) being (mis)used for specific container technologies  despite the tag description clearly guiding against it (emphasis mine):

> Use for generic questions on containers **that do not fall under a
>   specific container technology,** like Docker, LXC, FreeBSD Jails,
>   OpenBSD sysjails, Solaris Containers, WPARs, etc. Also use where the
>   specific technology is not relevant to the question.

Sample questions where I'd consider the tag misused:

- [Networking between Docker containers](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/networking-between-docker-containers)
- [Windows Service installation on Docker Container](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/windows-service-installation-on-docker-container)
- [Developing inside a Docker image?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/developing-inside-a-docker-image)

I also just noticed misused re-tagging efforts, for example:

- https://devops.stackexchange.com/revisions/3349/3
- https://devops.stackexchange.com/revisions/2411/4

Comment: For information, we can merge the tags when making them synonyms, so the number of questions is not really a problem, I let the community voice toward wich form is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend just merging [container](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/container) into [containers](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers) without a synonym. The system *should* have blocked the tag being produced when its pluralised form already existed... but evidently, it didn't.

The moderator merge tool can be used here to silently retag every question with [container](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/container) into [containers](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers), and then there's no need for a synonym as the tag guidance should hopefully prevent any future taggers from creating the duplicate tag.

Comment: Done as suggested.